# Download and install proprietary wireless driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, system-installation

I successfully installed 10.04 LTS on my Dell Mini 9, but could not wirelessly access the internet, so I went to "Hardware Drivers" but there were no proprietary drivers listed.

This surprised me, because when I ran 11.10 off a USB drive, I could install the driver and get wireless internet access.  (11.10 won't install on my 3.8-GB hard drive.)

My thought is to:  (1) identify the appropriate driver, (2) download it off the internet onto my Windows computer, (3) load the driver onto a USB drive, (4) plug that USB drive into my Mini 9, (5) take any steps necessary to get my system to see the driver (in the "Hardware Drivers" window)(by copying off the USB drive to somewhere on the system?), (6) go through the process of activating that driver, and (7) successfully connect wirelessly to the internet.

Does the above process make sense?  Can it be done?  If so, how?  Or is there an alternate approach like this that would work?

I've looked at similar questions and answers on this forum and they all look like they apply to something different.  Right now, my 10.04 installation is not giving me wireless internet access, and the only physical connection possible is a USB drive (to "feed" it a driver or whatever it needs to establish wireless connectivity).

I get in over my head quickly when typing commands, and am fairly new to Ubuntu.  Can anyone help, or do I need to go back to square one and try some entirely different Ubuntu installation?  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Good action plan. Please post the output of this: "sudo lshw -C network" to identify the network

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is late:

However you have 2 options:

1. Upgrade your Ubuntu to the latest version as you said, which will fix the problem.

or

2.You can go to the driver's website and download the driver (windows version). Using an application called "Ndiswrapper" in Linux. you can make the driver that was built for windows work in Ubuntu.

Here is the full "HOW TO" for the second step:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper